# How to estimate revenue based on categorical data?

Tags: statistics

How do I calculate the following example:

| Customer Spent | Number of Customers |
| --- | --- |
| [0 - 10 ] | 5 |
| (10 - 50] | 15 |
| (50 - 150] | 20 |
| (150 - 300] | 10 |

Say I want to estimate the total revenue, so I tried to use the median of each range and times the corresponding number of customers, 5 * 5 + 30 * 15 + 100 * 20 + 225 * 10 = 4725. Is it a valid approach?

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: There isn't really enough information here to say much.  Maybe each of the $10$ people in the bottom row spent $300$, maybe the each spent $150$, who knows?  Bu those two cases would give very different result.  If you want to use the midpoint of each interval, fine....but just be clear that it could be far off.

Comment: That's a very reasonable approach, although you don't really know that the average per-customer spend in each range is close to the midpoint. To be safe, you could calculate upper and lower bounds on the total, based on the upper and lower limits of the ranges.

Comment: Of course, ideally you could go back to whatever data source was used to create the table and calculate the exact revenue. Whatever process was used to generate the summary could also compute the exact sum at essentially no additional computational cost.